# byte? doesn't work as a parameter type in an iBatis parameterMap

Tags: configuration, ibatis, ibatis.net

According to [the iBatis docs](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s06.html), using "byte?" as a type value should work in `parameterMap`.  I'm using DataMapper version 1.6.1.

The error message I'm getting is: **Could not load type from string value 'byte?'**.

It's a configuration exception which shows this information in the stack trace:

> The error occurred while loading
>   SqlMap.
>
> - Check the parameter mapping typeHandler attribute '' (must be a
>     ITypeHandlerCallback implementation).
> - The error occurred in [sqlMap embedded="MyApp.Data.Config.Rate.xml, MyApp" Mxmlns="http://ibatis.apache.org/dataMapper"]
> - Check the Rate.InsertParams.]

Here's the XML block for Rate.InsertParams:

```
<parameterMaps>
<parameterMap id="InsertParams" class="RateCategory">
  <parameter property="RateId" column="RateId" type="int"/>
  <parameter property="Name" column="Name" type="string" size="32"/>
  <parameter property="Charge" column="Charge" type="decimal?"/>
  <parameter property="ChargeTypeId" column="ChargeTypeId" type="byte?"/>
</parameterMap>
```

Any ideas why it won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of asking and posting, the final answer is that the docs are wrong.

[The official iBatis.Net forum had this to say](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mybatisnet-user/IDP-eBJxbPw/discussion):

"You have a few options:

1. just use type="byte"
2. don't specify the type
3. byte? is syntactic sugar System.Nullable`1[[System.Byte]]"

Which is basically what I had already figured out myself.  int? works but byte? doesn't.  Neither does short? or long?.

The docs need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there isn't any "byte?" alias. [Here is a proof](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Persistence-Frameworks/iBATIS.NET/IBatisNet/Common/Utilities/TypesResolver/TypeRegistry.cs.htm).

You can also figure out what is for sure supported and what not from this file.

"Code never lies." Documentation does :(